# Waiting for another request in Django view

Tags: python, django

The title is pretty much self explaining, I need for one of my views to wait for another view to be called or timeout. It would look something like this:

```
class WaitingView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        ...do_things
        called = wait_for_DeblockingView_or_timeout()
        if called:
            return Response(200)
        return Response(408)


class DeblockingView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        ...do_things
        send_some_signal_to_unlock()
        return Response(200)
```

I already have tried to use the `Event` object of the `threading` module, making use of its `wait()` and `set()` methods, but either I'm doing it wrong either it's just not the way to go for this use case. More about that attempt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61921394/threading-event-wait-in-django-application).

Comment: I think this is a [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In a REST-API, each request should be self-contained and not depend on other requests. So I think your approach is a bit off. I read your linked question but I can't see how it's related to the backend. I don't think a user should need to tell the backend that he/she have started taking a scan, it should be solely in the frontend. But it could be because you've left some details out for brevity.

Comment: If you have to do it this way, then I'd suggest that the `/rfid/create/` endpoint doesn't wait, but instead stores a datetime value in the database that tells when the request was made and returns. Then you could just check if this time is valid when you do a request to `/rfid/assign/`. If that doesn't work, you could set up a Celery task that fires up and sends a signal after the specified time.

Comment: I'm open to any approach, the only requirements I have is for the frontend to say to the user 'Hey, you have x seconds to do this action', and after x seconds or the action was made say 'Too late' or 'Ok it's done'. I don't picture how how a Celery task would help, but I like your first idea, I need to move the time constraint for the user on the frontend and condition the call to `/assign/` accordingly. Thank you, it might be the light I deeply needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session` variable to share data between views :

```
class WaitingView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        ...do_things
        called = request.session.get('deblocking_call')
        if called is True:
            del request.session['deblocking_call']
            return Response(200)
        return Response(408)


class DeblockingView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        ...do_things
        request.session['deblocking_call'] = True

        return Response(200) ## I would use 'return redirect("waiting_view")'
```